# A problem with the scalar product of a free vectorial space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ the space of free vectors from the geometric space.

Prove that:

$\langle AB,AC\rangle =|AB|\cdot |AC|\cos(\angle(AB,AC))$
is a scalar product,

where

$AB$ and $AC$ are vectors
 and

$\angle(AB,AC)$ is the angle between $AB$ and $AC$ counted in the trigonometrical sense.

I tried choosing a base in $V$, so I can get the bilinear form from it,but I don't know how I can obtain it.

Please,could you help me at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three segments $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$ form a triangle. Let $\theta = \angle(AB,AC)$. Then use the law of cosines to get

$$ |BC|^2 = |AB|^2 + |AC|^2 - 2 \cdot |AB| \cdot |AC| \cdot \cos(\theta) $$

Solve for the term you are interested in:

$$ |AB| \, |AC| \cos(\theta) = \frac{|AB|^2+|AC|^2-|BC|^2}{2} \tag{$\star$} $$

Now do exactly what you suggested: pick a basis for $V$, and write $AB$ and $AC$ in coordinates as vectors centered at the origin:

$$ AB = (x_1,\dots,x_n), \quad AC = (y_1,\dots,y_n) $$

Then $|AB|^2 = \sum_i x_i^2$ and $|AC|^2 = \sum_i y_i^2$. Since $BC = AC - AB$, you get that

$$ |BC|^2 = \sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2 = \sum_i (x_i^2 + y_i^2 - 2x_iy_i) $$

Now plug everything into equation $(\star)$:

$$ |AB||AC|\cos(\theta) = \frac{\sum_i 2x_iy_y}{2} = \sum_i x_iy_i $$

This is precisely the standard inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I don't understand this:

Comment: Now do exactly what you suggested: pick a basis for VV, and write ABAB and ACAC in coordinates as vectors centered at the origin:

AB=(x1,…,xn),AC=(y1,…,yn)

Comment: Please,Nick Ovenhouse,could you explain me what does it mean?

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.I resolved my question.